# Optimal meeting point in directed graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, optimization, shortest-path, weighted-graphs

Let $G(V, E)$ be a edge-weighted directed connected graph and $v_1, \dots, v_n \in V$ be some vertices. Let $d(a, b)$ denote the length of the shortest path from $a$ to $b$, for $a,b \in V$.

I need to find a vertex $v \in V$ such that $$\sum_{i=1}^n d(v_i, v)^2$$ is minimal. What is the most time-efficient algorithm to solve this problem? Could I do any better than computing shortest paths from all $v_i$ to all other vertices in the graph?

Real-world example: $n$ friends are looking for a place for a meeting.

This is similar to [closeness centrality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrality#Closeness_centrality), but here I have a sum of *squared* distances rather than sum of distances.

Comment: You are dealing with *directed* *weighted* graphs (very general), and it makes it very difficult to find a fast algorithm, unless there is some other constraint such as Euclidean distance, metric space or some other properties?

Comment: @emab No special constraints, unfortunately :(...

Comment: Why not using parallel algorithms?

Comment: @emab Which particular algorithm do you mean? Or just compute shortest paths in parallel threads?

Comment: Just run single source shortest path for every vertex in parallel on multiple threads or cpu.

Comment: Without an embedding in $\mathbb{R}^2$, you probably won't be able to get any better than checking all possible paths as you mentioned.

Comment: You could run shortest paths between all pairs of vertices (Ford-Fulkerson, $O(n^3)$) and take it from there.

Comment: By "directed connected graph", do you mean weakly connected or strongly connected? [ https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConnectedDigraph.html ]. Also, can we assume that the edge weights are positive?